# Multiple pie charts with R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I have previously done multiple line charts using facet wrap with tables such as below, but for some reason I'm not having much luck doing the same with pie charts;

```
test <- data.frame(CONFIDENCE = c(rep("Mconfid", 3), rep("Hconfid", 3), rep("SHconfid", 3)),
                 POPULATION = c(rep(c("African","East_Asian","European"),3)),
                 AMOUNT = c(0.06, 0.23, 0.71, 0.00, 0.40, 0.60, 0.00, 0.10, 0.90))
test

  CONFIDENCE POPULATION AMOUNT
1    Mconfid    African   0.06
2    Mconfid East_Asian   0.23
3    Mconfid   European   0.71
4    Hconfid    African   0.00
5    Hconfid East_Asian   0.40
6    Hconfid   European   0.60
7   SHconfid    African   0.00
8   SHconfid East_Asian   0.10
9   SHconfid   European   0.90
```

I would like 3 pie charts to facet wrap or grid on "CONFIDENCE" using ggplot2

Thanks

If anyone would like to do multiple line charts, here is what works for me:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=POPULATION, y=AMOUNT, group=CONFIDENCE, color=CONFIDENCE)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ CONFIDENCE)
```

Comment: Can you show us code of your previous attempt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For pie chart in `ggplot` you need to set `x` to `""` and then add `coord_polar` (theme is just to remove values).

```
ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=AMOUNT, group=POPULATION, color=POPULATION, fill=POPULATION)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + facet_wrap(~ CONFIDENCE) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid  = element_blank())
```

With the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, works great! I gave you an upvote but does not register because I have less than 15 posts.

Comment: How would you modify the above script if you wanted to use it outside RStudio such as in a Linux environment. I used it in Linux terminal and printed to file by adding :  png("Multi_Pie1.png") and dev.off(), but it is only working inside RStudio.

Comment: `?ggsave` perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps also care a bit more about your audience https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle